# Help reverse my array sort comparison

Tags: php, sorting, reverse

I have my code working perfectly how I want it to, but the problem is my code is sorting by highest value to lowest. Can you help me reverse it so that when I print out the first 10 it is actually the "10 newest" (meaning the lowest duration)?

Thanks so much

```
function compareStreamDurations($a, $b)
{
     if ($a["duration"] == $b["duration"]) 
     {
        return 0;
     }
     return ($a["duration"] > $b["duration"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($onlineStreams, 'compareStreamDurations');

for ( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ )
{
    echo '<p>', $onlineStreams[$i]["duration"] ,'</p>';
}
```

The solutions posted below (reversing the sign) are NOT working. I'm doing a print_r of $onlineStreams before and after the usort function call and they are both the same.

Comment: What does your `$onlineStreams` array look like? Does the "duration" key exist in all array elements? Are the "duration" values numeric?

Comment: "I'm doing a print_r of $onlineStreams before and after the usort function call and they are both the same?" Does that mean that the sort isn't working in either case, or that the result of the sort is the same whether you compare with `>` or `<`? Have you tried checking the return value of usort to make sure that the sort succeeded?

Answer (score 3):

Just change your greater than to a less than:

```
return ($a["duration"] < $b["duration"]) ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: This did not work when I tested using the for loop (shown above)

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the greater than sign and making it a less than, like this:

```
function compareStreamDurations($a, $b)
{
     if ($a["duration"] == $b["duration"]) 
     {
        return 0;
     }
     return ($a["duration"] < $b["duration"]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Reversing the > to < did not rearrange properly. It is the same either way